# Can a Docker made from Ubuntu 16.04.01 run on 16.04.5?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Can a Docker made from Ubuntu 16.04.01 run on 16.04.5? Can all versions of Ubuntu run a Docker from all other versions of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It can.

The main idea of containerizing app is to package your app, dependency and all other necessary stuffs that are required to run your application into a single package. So, wherever there is docker engine, you can run your docker image. No matter what is your OS version. All the things that are require to run your app are already packaged with the image.

Look at the docker's official definition of [What is a Container](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container)